# Create C# delegate type with ref parameter at runtime

Tags: dynamic, parameters, delegates, pass-by-reference

I need to create a delegate type with a `ref` parameter at runtime.

If I knew the parameter type(s) at compile time, I could use an explicit delegate type declaration, for example:

```
// S is some struct / value type, e.g. int or Guid
delegate void VoidDelSRef (ref S s);
Type td = typeof (VoidDelSRef);
```

That type `td` is used to create a C#4 expression tree, which is compiled into a delegate.

Since the code in my expression tree modifies the parameter `s`, I need to pass `s` by reference.

I have to support any type `S`, so I can't use an explicit delegate type declaration, because I only have `Type ts = typeof (S)` and its `ref` type `Type tsr = ts.MakeByRefType ()`.

I tried to use `Expression.GetActionType (tsr)`, but it does not allow `ref` types.

How do I build a delegate with `ref` parameters at runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 4, you can use the [**`Expression.GetDelegateType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.getdelegatetype.aspx) method. Unlike `GetActionType`, it works fine with `ByRef` types.

E.g.:

```
// void MyDelegate(ref int arg)
var delType = Expression.GetDelegateType(typeof(int).MakeByRefType(), 
                                         typeof(void));
```

If you are on .NET 3.5, this method is not available. I recommend taking a look at its implementation (with a decompiler) if you want to replicate its functionality. It doesn't have too many dependencies; it's definitely doable.

Comment: Umm, it works - almost. GetDelegateType creates the type I need.  So Ani answered my question completely.  However, I still have some problems to call the delegate.  But I am still analyzing what extacly is going on.  I noticed some unexpected behaviour of GetDelegateType: When called multiple times with exactly the same parameters, each call returns new type instances, so they are not reference-equal.  Here is more info: [DLR @ CodePlex - Bug with Expression.GetDelegateType and user defined struct as ref](http://dlr.codeplex.com/discussions/209768). I'll be back when I know what to ask :)

Comment: I think I understand my problem now. In the function building the expression tree, I specify the delegate type using `Expression.GetDelegateType()`. But I cant cast the compiled delegate to `VoidDelSRef`, most likely because each GetDelegateType returns a new type instance. So I call the delegate dlg like this: `S s = new S (); var dpl = new object[] { s }; dlg.DynamicInvoke (dpl); s = (S) dpl[0];`. Slightly less efficient, I guess, but now it works :)